# "Can't find file mysql/plugin.frm" when starting up MySQL

Tags: mysql

When I start my MySQL server, I get this error:

```
/usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

I have run `mysql_upgrade` to rebuild it, and it works to rebuild. Before I did that, I removed and installed MySQL. However, when I tried to re-start, I get the same error. I am sure it is not a permission problem, as all files and directories are created by the `mysql` user.

Could you advise me on how to fix this error?

Comment: selinux can also cause this problem.

Answer (score 18):

If you have mysql data directory at non-standard location and your system has apparmor, ensure that `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` has your data directory whitelisted. The configuration should look like:

```
/mysql/data/dir/ r, #trailing slash is mandatory
/mysql/data/dir/** rwk,
```

Apparmor daemon has to be restarted after you make any changes to config.

Comment: `apparmor` comes back to wake us up from time to time, just so we don't forget about him ...

Comment: Wow! lot of time looking for this answer. Thanks!

Comment: In my case I also use a custom temp dir, and I found I needed to imitate some lines from `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/user-tmp`. When I put `owner /mysql-tmp/** rwkl, /mysql-tmp/ r,` into `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld` it started working for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 13):

Are you sure that it's not about permissions? 
*errno: 13*:

```
$ perror 13
OS error code  13:  Permission denied
```

The first thing to try is to change the ownership of the datadir of *MySQL*,
for example, if you run *MySQL* with user *mysql*:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /path/to/datadir
```

Another thing to check is if the *mysqld* process owner (most probably *mysql*)
has the necessary privileges for the destination defined as *tmpdir*.
And if for whatever reason the above doesn't work,
try to trace the *mysqld* process to see where and why it gets *permission denied*:

```
strace -fp$(/sbin/pidof mysqld) -o /tmp/my_trace.log
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue when upgrading from MySQL 5.1 to 5.7.  It appears that user _mysql_ lost ownership of the _/var/lib/mysql_ directory.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I needed to place the MySQL data directory including `ibdata1` folder into another partitioning because my `ibdata1` was growing too fast and memory issue occurred. For that, I had to change my.cnf file like below.

my.cnf was:

```
datadir         =  /var/lib/mysql
```

my.cnf now:

```
datadir         = /home/ubuntu/data/mysql
```

I tried,

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql  /home/ubuntu/data/mysql
```

but still got the same above error. Then I tried to change the `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` file. It worked well for me.

We should whitelist our new folder in `usr.sbin.mysqld`.

```
 # /var/lib/mysql/ r,
 #/var/lib/mysql/** rwk,
```

Instead of the above lines add,

```
 /home/ubuntu/data/mysql/ r,
 /home/ubuntu/data/mysql/** rwk,
```

Then restart MySQL server.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dimitre. This problem arises mostly due to insufficient permissions. Change the ownership of MySql root folder to mysql.

```
chown -R mysql:mysql [mysql root folder]
```

You might want to change the permission of Mysql scripts to your custom user though.

```
chown my_mysql:my_mysql [mysqld etc]
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running SELinux the following may help as well...

```
 $ -> ls -lZa
 $ -> chcon -R -v -u system_u -t mysqld_db_t /var/lib/mysql
 $ -> ls -lZa
```

Comment: For me, doing `restorecon -R /var/lib/mysql` helped to correctly restore SELinux settings for the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after I upgraded from 5.5 to 5.6.

Strangely, it looked like the `mysql` user had been removed and re-created, which had caused all the mysql files to essentially 'lose' their permissions ...

I found this out by going to the mysql dir (Which in my case was not the default dir, as I have moved it) and saw that the owner was just a uuid and guid number ... So, I just ran `chown mysql:mysql` on all the dirs and files, and voila

Answer (score -1):

This simple `chown` worked for me also, no more crashing process:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql  /var/lib/mysql
```

Thankfully, playing with apparmor gets complicated and hard to edit.